# ThunderBird math equations

Tags: thunderbird, equations

I just started using Thunderbird 78.14.0. I would like to put math equations into the email body.

I can go to :
`insert` -> `math` and type some latex equations. However, the end receiver if not using thunderbird too will not see the equations correctly.

I can use the HTML function by putting the equations in here: https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php and getting the corresponding HTML code. However, the quality of the equations is very poor.

Any way to fix this?

Best Regards

Comment: It might be thunderbird specific coding, or simply the other client is not capable of showing equations correctly. If you want reliable results, you need either to insert them as picture, or embed in attached documents.

Answer (score 0):

A solution a bit more portable might use SVG format.

1. Convert your LaTeX formula to SVG (there are plenty of tools to do this. You will find some here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg+conversion)
2. Copy the SVG code (basically something in `<svg>` `</svg>` tags)
3. In Thunderbird, go to `insert` -> `HTML...` and paste the SVG code here (including `<svg>` tags of course !)